# Is it possible to redirect all subdomains except www to a specific directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, .htaccess

I would like any directory *.example.com (bar.example.com, foo.example.com, etc..) to direct to the folder /home/user/htdocs/subdir/

www.example.com and example.com should remain unaffected.

Is this possible with htacecss, or another route?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by setting up two virtual hosts via the Apache configuration. For example:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/user/htdocs
  ServerName www.example.com example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/user/htdocs/subdir
  ServerName *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the declaring in your Apache configuration file the directives for www.example.com and example.com, you can set an extra `VirtualHost` entry with any subdomain as `ServerName` and a wildcard `ServerAlias` like so to point every subdomain there.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/user/htdocs/subdir
  ServerName foobar.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: You must declare a servername (any would do)